# QT Creator exits with code 0 when running program

Tags: qt, opencv

I am trying to run a simple OpenCV program in QT Creator 2.3, QT 4.7.4.  I know the syntax is correct, but my program does not get run.  When I run it, I simply get the qtcreator_process_stub.exe window with "`Press <RETURN> to close this window...`".

Why is this?  My .pro file looks as such:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = myQtConsoleProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\release\\include

LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\release\\lib \
-lopencv_core231.dll \
-lopencv_highgui231.dll \
-lopencv_imgproc231.dll \
-lopencv_features2d231.dll \
-lopencv_calib3d231.dll
```

The application output is

```
Starting C:\Users\chris\QT\myQtConsoleProject-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release\release\myQtConsoleProject.exe...
C:\Users\chris\QT\myQtConsoleProject-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Release
```

\release\myQtConsoleProject.exe exited with code 0

The contents of my source code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main() {
        printf("not outputting...\n");
        cv::Mat image= cv::imread("C:/temp/img.jpg");
        cv::namedWindow("My Image");
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        cv::waitKey(50000);
        return 1;
}
```

I've added `C:\opencv\release\bin` to my path.

Comment: No one can really start to give you an answer without seeing what you have in your main.cpp

Comment: Sorry.  I've included the source code now

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your console window does not show any lines except the "Press  to close" line means that your application does not output anything to the console.

I see you have a console project configured, meaning it has no GUI. But due to the fact that your program compiles fine this might not be a problem.

Can you post the code of your main() function? The behavior you describe seems to be related to your code, not the project configuration.

Comment: I think you need to create a QCoreApplication object in order to get the console output working. What does cv::imshow do, does it rely on Qt Gui parts maybe? You could try creating a new Console or GUI application which will already give you a main() method. Then extend that method by the OpenCV code, but leave the parts generated by Qt Creator there.